# Underline text for email message in PHP

Tags: php

I need to underline some words or make them bold in an email message that is sent using PHP's `mail()` function. For example, `$message = "_Posted By: _";` or `$message = "(u)Posted By: (/u)"`; or `$message = "(strong)Posted By: (/strong)";` does not work.

Any suggestions will be most appreciated!

P.S. I used brackets instead of tags in these examples to prevent them from displaying in **bold** in this question.

Comment: you should post code in "code" style. Look at the toolbar your editor -> `this is code style`

Comment: Why not use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)?

Answer (score 2):

set content type to HTML in headers:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

use html tags in your message:

```
$message = "<b>Posted By: </b>";
```

send mail with headers:

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

you can also check [example # 3](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp) from w3cschools.com to learn more

Comment: I know I must not say Thank-you, but just to let you know that your answer works perfectly and solved the problem :-)

Comment: you are welcome, please accept it as answer if it works